# Property to set a type and return different type

Tags: c#, variables, properties

I know that a property can be set as a single type and not to be changed once set, but is there a way to create a `property` or a `property-like object` that sets an `int` while returns a `string`?

I'm constantly creating variables like an `int` which will later on be used as `string` only and never to be used as `int` once set. So in that case i would always have to make a lot of conversions considering that it's not just one type to another.

Comment: No, but you could have a `SetFoo(int)` and a `GetFoo` method returning a `string`. It's pretty unusual though.

Comment: Why don't use `ToString()` on an `int` when (string)needed?

Comment: declare as an int, and once you need a string, use it's to string `variable.toString()`

Comment: You can write your own getters and setters instead of using the built in properties. And also - if you always have to use it as a string - why to create it as an int?

Comment: You can shorten the conversion to `string s = 123 + "";`

Comment: I'm already using `ToString()` and i need to create an `int` because the value of it will be the on-hold output of multiple values after a specific operation which in that case the output holder needs to be of an `int` type and once is set will be used as `string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
struct strint 
{
   private int i; // 0 by default

   public static implicit operator strint(int value) {
       return new strint { i = value };
   }  

   public static implicit operator string(strint value) {
       return value.i.ToString();
   }

   public static implicit operator int(strint value) {
       return value.i;
   }
}
```

Sample use:

```
strint a = 1;
a += 2;         // 3
int i = a;      // 3
string s = a;   // "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need it only as a string and only once as integer (during initialization) go with the string-value:

```
int readonly _myProp;
string MyProp { get { return _myProp.ToString(); } }

MyClass(int theValue
{
    this._myProp = theValue;
}
```

The `readonly`  moreover ensures that a user can only set the value during intialization of your class.

Comment: what if i want to change the value of _myProp?

Comment: OP said he´s just setting it once and never changes it.

Comment: You can´t set a value at runtime to a constant, so I doubt this is what OP wants.

Comment: definitely, so this is what OP wants, a constant variable :)

Comment: There is a difference between `readonly` and `const` in terms of when you can set their value. However it´s not clear (at least to me) if OP needs to set a value at runtime (=`readonly`) or at compiletime (=`const`).